# parsing mysql:/// sqlite:/// URLs

Tags: regex, perl, url

We've got this little regexp in a module to parse URLs like the following:

```
if( my ($conn, $driver, $user, $pass, $host, $port, $dbname, $table_name, $tparam_name, $tparam_value, $conn_param_string) =
    $url =~ m{^((\w*)://(?:(\w+)(?:\:([^/\@]*))?\@)?(?:([\w\-\.]+)(?:\:(\d+))?)?/(\w*))(?:/(\w+)(?:\?(\w+)=(\w+))?)?((?:;(\w+)=(\w+))*)$} ) {
```

mysql://anonymous@my.self.com:1234/dbname

and now we want to add parsing of sqlite URLs which can be like this:

sqlite:///dbname_which_is_a_file

But it won't work with absolute paths like: sqlite:///tmp/dbname_which_is_a_file

What is the *proper* way of doing this?

Comment: by the way when dealing with this kind of long not //x RE, you could find [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain/Explain.pm) useful. I put this specific regexp as example [here](http://pablomarin-garcia.blogspot.com/2011/05/deofuscating-large-or-complex-regular.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the regular expression is that does not work with paths longer than two elements. It splits them into db_name and table_name (if any). Also this regular expression does not work with SQLite special filenames like ':memory' (that are very useful for tests).

In order to have a maintainable RE approach, the best way to work with this is to have a dispatch table with the main protocols that need different parsing and have a subrutine for each different approach. Also will help have a RE with //x, so it can have comments and help its maintainability:

```
 sub test_re{
     my $url =shift;
     my $x={};
     @$x{qw(conn driver user pass host port dbname table_name tparam_name tparam_value conn_param_string)} =
         $url =~ m{
                ^(
                  (\w*)
                  ://
                  (?:
                    (\w+) # user
                    (?:
                      \:
                      ([^/\@]*) # password 
                    )?
                    \@
                  )? # could not have user,pass
                  (?:
                    ([\w\-\.]+) #host
                    (?:
                      \:
                      (\d+) # port
                    )? # port optional
                  )? # host and port optional
                  / # become in a third '/' if no user pass host and port
                  (\w*) # get the db (only until the first '/' is any). Will not work with full paths for sqlite.
                )
                (?:
                  /  # if tables
                  (\w+) # get table
                  (?:
                    \? # parameters
                    (\w+)
                    =
                   (\w+)
                  )? # parameter is conditional but would have always a tablename
                )? # conditinal table and parameter
                (
                  (?:
                    ;
                    (\w+)
                    =
                    (\w+)
                  )* # rest of parameters if any
                )
                $
             }x;
     return $x;
 }
```

But I will recommend to use [URI::Split](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI/URI/Split.pm) (less code verbosity than [URI](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI/URI.pm)), and then split the path as needed.

You can see the difference of using the RE vs URI::Split here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use feature ':5.10';
use strict;
use URI::Split qw(uri_join uri_split);
use Data::Dumper;

my $urls = [qw(
             mysql://anonymous@my.self.com:1234/dbname
             mysql://anonymous@my.self.com:1234/dbname/tablename
             mysql://anonymous@my.self.com:1234/dbname/pathextra/tablename
             sqlite:///dbname_which_is_a_file
             sqlite:///tmp/dbname_which_is_a_file
             sqlite:///tmp/db/dbname_which_is_a_file
             sqlite:///:dbname_which_is_a_file
             sqlite:///:memory
             )];



foreach my $url (@$urls) {
    print Dumper(test_re($url));
    print Dumper(uri_split($url));
}
```

Results:

```
 [...]
 == testing sqlite:///dbname_which_is_a_file ==
 - RE
 $VAR1 = {
           'pass' => undef,
           'port' => undef,
           'dbname' => 'dbname_which_is_a_file',
           'host' => undef,
           'conn_param_string' => '',
           'conn' => 'sqlite:///dbname_which_is_a_file',
           'tparam_name' => undef,
           'tparam_value' => undef,
           'user' => undef,
           'table_name' => undef,
           'driver' => 'sqlite'
         };

 - URI::Split
 $VAR1 = 'sqlite';
 $VAR2 = '';
 $VAR3 = '/dbname_which_is_a_file';
 $VAR4 = undef;
 $VAR5 = undef;

 == testing sqlite:///tmp/dbname_which_is_a_file ==
 - RE
 $VAR1 = {
           'pass' => undef,
           'port' => undef,
           'dbname' => 'tmp',
           'host' => undef,
           'conn_param_string' => '',
           'conn' => 'sqlite:///tmp',
           'tparam_name' => undef,
           'tparam_value' => undef,
           'user' => undef,
           'table_name' => 'dbname_which_is_a_file',
           'driver' => 'sqlite'
         };

 - URI::Split
 $VAR1 = 'sqlite';
 $VAR2 = '';
 $VAR3 = '/tmp/dbname_which_is_a_file';
 $VAR4 = undef;
 $VAR5 = undef;

== testing sqlite:///tmp/db/dbname_which_is_a_file ==
- RE
$VAR1 = {
          'pass' => undef,
          'port' => undef,
          'dbname' => undef,
          'host' => undef,
          'conn_param_string' => undef,
          'conn' => undef,
          'tparam_name' => undef,
          'tparam_value' => undef,
          'user' => undef,
          'table_name' => undef,
          'driver' => undef
        };

- URI::Split
$VAR1 = 'sqlite';
$VAR2 = '';
$VAR3 = '/tmp/db/dbname_which_is_a_file';
$VAR4 = undef;
$VAR5 = undef;

== testing sqlite:///:memory ==
- RE
$VAR1 = {
          'pass' => undef,
          'port' => undef,
          'dbname' => undef,
          'host' => undef,
          'conn_param_string' => undef,
          'conn' => undef,
          'tparam_name' => undef,
          'tparam_value' => undef,
          'user' => undef,
          'table_name' => undef,
          'driver' => undef
        };

- URI::Split
$VAR1 = 'sqlite';
$VAR2 = '';
$VAR3 = '/:memory';
$VAR4 = undef;
$VAR5 = undef;
```

Answer (score 4):

The CPAN module, [URI::Split](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aSplit) will work out a lot better in the long run than a fragile regexp.  Here's the synopsis from its POD:

```
use URI::Split qw(uri_split uri_join);
($scheme, $auth, $path, $query, $frag) = uri_split($uri);
$uri = uri_join($scheme, $auth, $path, $query, $frag);
```

A more general module (more flexible, and more complex) would be [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI), but for simple uses its additional complexity may not be necessary.

By the way, a URI is a Uniform Resource Identifier, which is a superset, or parent to a URL.  A URL is a specific application of URIs.